# Low speeds of wifi hotspot created on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, android, hot-spot

**(Its a humble request to not close down this thread)**

OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Android Phone - Samsung Galaxy S3(flashed it with CM13)

Laptop - HP-ENVY (Model : 6-1002TX)

I created a hotspot on ubuntu using 2 ways:

1. Edit Connections->Wifi(change IPv4 to shared)->change mode to ap.
2. Using Ubuntu's in-built option. System Settings->Network->Use as hotspot(ad-hoc).

   - Phone detects the hotspot when 1st way is followed. Problem is I won't get sufficient speed although my laptop has high speed connection.
   - Phone doesn't detect hotspot at all. I ping the IP(ifconfig wlan0) that is assigned to wlan0, output is normal.

I know android phones don't have ad-hoc support. Already tried all solutions to enable ad-hoc support.I guess its a problem with wifi drivers. Here is the info about network interfaces.

```
 - -network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:c1500000-c1503fff 
 - -network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 08:ed:b9:5b:d2:a4
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.19.0-25-generic firmware=610.812 ip=10.42.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Please provide objective results of network connection performance tests you did with the device on the hotspot, another wifi connection and a another device on the hotspot for comparison that indicates that the problem is the performance of the hotspot and the involved software components, not just one particular device using it or that the hardware of the device hosting the hotspot isn't suited for hosting hotspots.